# Pubnub subscribe to 1 to 1 chat

Tags: ios, pubnub, user-presence

in pubnub group chat is easy,but i could not find proper way to 1 to 1 chat, i followed http://pubnub.github.io/pubnub-design-patterns/2015/03/05/Inbound-Channel-Pattern.html.
so conclusion for that each user subscribe to unique channel,isn't it?

```
 PNConfiguration *configuration = [PNConfiguration configurationWithPublishKey:@“mypublishkey” subscribeKey:@“mysubskey”];
  configuration.uuid=@“myuuid”;//unique id help to find presence
 configuration.presenceHeartbeatValue = 120;
//unsubscribe from channel until no response in 120 sec

  configuration.presenceHeartbeatInterval = 30;//send to server each 30 second
      self.client = [PubNub clientWithConfiguration:configuration];
      [self.client addListener:self];
_delegateconfig=delegate;

    // Subscribe to demo channel with presence observation
    [self.client subscribeToChannels: @[channelname] withPresence:YES];
```

/*--for listing all user or channel---*/

i called hereNowWithCompletion
which shows all channel list that was ok

for example https://www.pubnub.com/docs/cocoa-objective-c/presence

/*--------for unsubscribe from channel--------*/

[self.client unsubscribeFromChannels:@[channelname] withPresence:YES];
not working,because when i call hereNowWithCompletion shows all list that was previous but after 120 sec that was ok,but i want instant reflation.

Comment: Yes, private chat is just a channel with only two users subscribed to the channel and publishing messages to that channel. hereNow is simply a means to find out who is actively subscribed to a channel(s). Review [Chat Fundamentals](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/chat-fundamentals) for more details on best practices with chat.

Comment: @craig-conover, thanks for replying,still i have confusion regarding that suppose 2 user want to chat with each other as per your suggestion, for example "channel_a-b",but if A send message to user B,then User B will not be able to  receive message from that channel until and unless User B subscribe for same channel, this delegate method will not call for user b untill he subscribe same channel- (void)client:(PubNub *)client didReceiveMessage:(PNMessageResult *)message

Comment: You are correct. So you need to have A invite B to the channel and wait for B to accept the invite (subscribe to the channel). But that isn't even necessary as B can just call history (Storage must be enabled) when B first subscribes to the channel.

Comment: @Craig Conover,thanks for support got it,through inbound channel

Answer (score 2):

it is an perfect concept for one to one chat with pubnub
http://pubnub.github.io/pubnub-design-patterns/2015/03/05/Inbound-Channel-Pattern.html